# Using ng-repeat to pull data from 2 different JSON files

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am not getting an errors, but cannot get my data to render. My structure is simple in that json files in one folder, views in another, scripts/controllers in another. Simply using the controller to do the work since it is a straight forward widget. Any ideas on what may be causing this to fail as I am not getting errors and I believe my mapping is correct.

My code:

updated view here:

```
<div class="col-md-5 propDtl" style="padding: 10px; display: block;" ng-repeat="item in items">
    <div class="listImg" style="float: left;">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" style="display: block;">
    </div>
    <div class="propTxt" style="margin-left: 220px; padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;">
      <p style="font-size: 22px; color: blue;">{{ item.address }}</p>
      <p style="font-size: 22px; color: blue;">{{ item.address }}</p>
      <p  style="font-size: 26px; color: black;">{{ item.cost }}</p>
      <ul>
        <li>{{ item.beds }}</li>
        <li>{{ item.baths }}</li>
        <li>{{ item.sq_ft }}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

original view:

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <h2>Awesome Listings Widget</h2>  
  <div class="listingsFilter">
    <a href="" class="btn btn-md btn-primary">Price</a>
    <a href="" class="btn btn-md btn-warning">Beds</a>
    <a href="" class="btn btn-md btn-success">Sq. ft.</a>
  </div>
  <div class="properties col-md-12" style="margin-top: 10px;">
      <div class="col-md-5 propDtl" style="padding: 10px; display: block;" ng-repeat="item in items">
        <div class="listImg" style="float: left;">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" style="display: block;">
        </div>
        <div class="propTxt" style="margin-left: 220px; padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;">
          <p style="font-size: 22px; color: blue;">{{ item.value.address }}</p>
          <p style="font-size: 22px; color: blue;">{{ item.value.address }}</p>
          <p  style="font-size: 26px; color: black;">{{ item.value.cost }}</p>
          <ul>
            <li>{{ item.value.beds }}</li>
            <li>{{ item.value.baths }}</li>
            <li>{{ item.value.sq_ft }}</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

my controller:

```
'use strict';
angular.module('zillowTestApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$filter',    
  function ($scope, $http, $filter) {

    $scope.items = [];

    $http.get('#/batmanReality.json').then(function(response){
    angular.forEach(response.data.__BATMAN_DATA__, function(value,key){
      $scope.items.push({ 
          address: key, 
          cost: value.cost,
          beds: value.beds,
          baths: value.baths,
          sq_ft: value.sq_ft
      });
    })
    });

    $http.get('#/supermanReality.json').then(function(response){
    angular.forEach(response.data.__SUPERMAN_DATA__, function(value,key){
      $scope.items.push({ 
          address: value.address, 
          price: value.cost,
          beds: value.beds,
          baths: value.baths,
          sq_ft: value.sq_ft
      });
    })
    });
}]);
```

And the 2 JSON files with their objects and properties.

```
window.__BATMAN_DATA__ = {
    "1806 E. Wayne Lane, Fort Dodge, IA 50501": {
        "cost": "849,950",
        "beds": "5",
        "baths": "3",
        "sq_ft": "4050",
        "img": "http://stevensegallery.com/200/200",
        "url": "http://trulia.com"
    },
    "1774 Kapow Drive, Hyattsville, MD 20782": {
        "cost": "419,950",
        "beds": "3",
        "baths": "2",
        "sq_ft": "1700",
        "img": "http://stevensegallery.com/200/200",
        "url": "http://trulia.com"
    },
    "773 Duhnuhnuhna Street, Essex, MD 21221": {
        "cost": "524,999",
        "beds": "3",
        "baths": "2",
        "sq_ft": "1980",
        "img": "http://stevensegallery.com/200/200",
        "url": "http://trulia.com"
    },
    "178 Pennyworth Avenue, Depew, NY 14043": {
        "cost": "619,999",
        "beds": "4",
        "baths": "1.5",
        "sq_ft": "2100",
        "img": "http://stevensegallery.com/200/200",
        "url": "http://trulia.com"
    }
};
```

and:

```
window.__SUPERMAN_DATA__ = {
    "items": [
        {
            "address": "7791 Luther Way, Knoxville, TN 37918",
            "price": "549999",
            "beds": "3",
            "baths": "2.5",
            "sqft": "3000",
            "built": "1976",
            "thumb": "http://fillmurray.com/150/150",
            "url": "http://zillow.com"
        },
        {
            "address": "1774 Kapow Drive, Hyattsville, MD 20782",
            "price": "419950",
            "beds": "3",
            "baths": "2",
            "sqft": "1700",
            "built": "2001",
            "thumb": "http://stevensegallery.com/200/200",
            "url": "http://zillow.com"
        },
        {
            "address": "3121 5th Street, Gotham, NY 27520",
            "price": "280000",
            "beds": "2",
            "baths": "1",
            "sqft": "",
            "built": "1948",
            "thumb": "http://fillmurray.com/150/150",
            "url": "http://zillow.com"
        },
        {
            "address": "178 Pennyworth Avenue, Depew, NY 14043",
            "price": "619999",
            "beds": "4",
            "baths": "1.5",
            "sqft": "2100",
            "built": "2014",
            "thumb": "http://stevensegallery.com/200/200",
            "url": "http://zillow.com"
        }
    ]
};
```

As you can see, I reference ng-repeat with "item in items" and structured the http.get to grab that way with the object. Ideas please?

Comment: does the `$http.get()` work?Can you verify it in the developers console? `window.__SUPERMAN_DATA__` is javascript not json.

Answer (score 1):

Please check your JSON. Think so JSON is not valid.

BatmanReality.json

```
{"batman" : {
"1806 E. Wayne Lane, Fort Dodge, IA 50501": {
    "cost": "849,950",
    "beds": "5",
    "baths": "3",
    "sq_ft": "4050",
    "img": "http://stevensegallery.com/200/200",
    "url": "http://trulia.com"
},
"1774 Kapow Drive, Hyattsville, MD 20782": {
    "cost": "419,950",
    "beds": "3",
    "baths": "2",
    "sq_ft": "1700",
    "img": "http://stevensegallery.com/200/200",
    "url": "http://trulia.com"
},
"773 Duhnuhnuhna Street, Essex, MD 21221": {
    "cost": "524,999",
    "beds": "3",
    "baths": "2",
    "sq_ft": "1980",
    "img": "http://stevensegallery.com/200/200",
    "url": "http://trulia.com"
},
"178 Pennyworth Avenue, Depew, NY 14043": {
    "cost": "619,999",
    "beds": "4",
    "baths": "1.5",
    "sq_ft": "2100",
    "img": "http://stevensegallery.com/200/200",
    "url": "http://trulia.com"
}}}
```

supermanReality.json

```
{"superman" : {
"items": [
    {
        "address": "7791 Luther Way, Knoxville, TN 37918",
        "price": "549999",
        "beds": "3",
        "baths": "2.5",
        "sqft": "3000",
        "built": "1976",
        "thumb": "http://fillmurray.com/150/150",
        "url": "http://zillow.com"
    },
    {
        "address": "1774 Kapow Drive, Hyattsville, MD 20782",
        "price": "419950",
        "beds": "3",
        "baths": "2",
        "sqft": "1700",
        "built": "2001",
        "thumb": "http://stevensegallery.com/200/200",
        "url": "http://zillow.com"
    },
    {
        "address": "3121 5th Street, Gotham, NY 27520",
        "price": "280000",
        "beds": "2",
        "baths": "1",
        "sqft": "",
        "built": "1948",
        "thumb": "http://fillmurray.com/150/150",
        "url": "http://zillow.com"
    },
    {
        "address": "178 Pennyworth Avenue, Depew, NY 14043",
        "price": "619999",
        "beds": "4",
        "baths": "1.5",
        "sqft": "2100",
        "built": "2014",
        "thumb": "http://stevensegallery.com/200/200",
        "url": "http://zillow.com"
    }
]}}
```

and

html:

```
<div class="properties col-md-12" style="margin-top: 10px;">
      <div class="col-md-5 propDtl" style="padding: 10px; display: block;" ng-repeat="item in items">
        <div class="listImg" style="float: left;">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" style="display: block;">
        </div>
        <div class="propTxt" style="margin-left: 220px; padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;">
          <p style="font-size: 22px; color: blue;">{{ item.address }}</p>
          <p style="font-size: 22px; color: blue;">{{ item.address }}</p>
          <p  style="font-size: 26px; color: black;">{{ item.cost }}</p>
          <ul>
            <li>{{ item.beds }}</li>
            <li>{{ item.baths }}</li>
            <li>{{ item.sq_ft }}</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Your Json, window.**BATMAN_DATA**  and window.**SUPERMAN_DATA** is not an array, it's object of objects. So please modify your json as-

```
window.__SUPERMAN_DATA__ = [

        {
            "address": "7791 Luther Way, Knoxville, TN 37918",
            "price": "549999",
            "beds": "3",
            "baths": "2.5",
            "sqft": "3000",
            "built": "1976",
            "thumb": "http://fillmurray.com/150/150",
            "url": "http://zillow.com"
        },
        {
            "address": "1774 Kapow Drive, Hyattsville, MD 20782",
            "price": "419950",
            "beds": "3",
            "baths": "2",
            "sqft": "1700",
            "built": "2001",
            "thumb": "http://stevensegallery.com/200/200",
            "url": "http://zillow.com"
        },
        {
            "address": "3121 5th Street, Gotham, NY 27520",
            "price": "280000",
            "beds": "2",
            "baths": "1",
            "sqft": "",
            "built": "1948",
            "thumb": "http://fillmurray.com/150/150",
            "url": "http://zillow.com"
        },
        {
            "address": "178 Pennyworth Avenue, Depew, NY 14043",
            "price": "619999",
            "beds": "4",
            "baths": "1.5",
            "sqft": "2100",
            "built": "2014",
            "thumb": "http://stevensegallery.com/200/200",
            "url": "http://zillow.com"
        }
    ];



 window.__BATMAN_DATA__ = [
       { "1806 E. Wayne Lane, Fort Dodge, IA 50501": {
            "cost": "849,950",
            "beds": "5",
            "baths": "3",
            "sq_ft": "4050",
            "img": "http://stevensegallery.com/200/200",
            "url": "http://trulia.com"
        }
},
        {"1774 Kapow Drive, Hyattsville, MD 20782": {
            "cost": "419,950",
            "beds": "3",
            "baths": "2",
            "sq_ft": "1700",
            "img": "http://stevensegallery.com/200/200",
            "url": "http://trulia.com"
        }
},
       { "773 Duhnuhnuhna Street, Essex, MD 21221": {
            "cost": "524,999",
            "beds": "3",
            "baths": "2",
            "sq_ft": "1980",
            "img": "http://stevensegallery.com/200/200",
            "url": "http://trulia.com"
        }
},
       { "178 Pennyworth Avenue, Depew, NY 14043": {
            "cost": "619,999",
            "beds": "4",
            "baths": "1.5",
            "sq_ft": "2100",
            "img": "http://stevensegallery.com/200/200",
            "url": "http://trulia.com"
        }
}
    ];
```